# Adding new suggestion rule in deequ

Tags: amazon-deequ

I would like to add several new rules in suggestions deequ workflow. For example deequ is offering check if column contains URL (containsURL). I would like to make corresponding suggestion rule.

I would appreciate suggestions how to do that.

Thanks,

Dejan

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation contains an [example](https://github.com/awslabs/deequ/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/amazon/deequ/examples/constraint_suggestion_example.md) for constraint suggestion. In the example, the constraint suggestion is executed via

```scala
val suggestionResult = ConstraintSuggestionRunner()
  .onData(data)
  .addConstraintRules(Rules.DEFAULT)
  .run()
```

The rules are passed in by specifying the argument to `addConstraintRules`. `Rules.DEFAULT`, the default set of rules to use, is defined in the `ConstraintSuggestionRunner` ([link](https://github.com/awslabs/deequ/blob/e4127fe2f29a34f9a27f4863ea70312d00a9df80/src/main/scala/com/amazon/deequ/suggestions/ConstraintSuggestionRunner.scala#L32)).

Hence, to add a new rule, you'd need to declare a rule that extends `ConstraintRule` ([link](https://github.com/awslabs/deequ/blob/e4127fe2f29a34f9a27f4863ea70312d00a9df80/src/main/scala/com/amazon/deequ/suggestions/rules/ConstraintRule.scala)) or one of its subtypes ([link](https://github.com/awslabs/deequ/tree/e4127fe2f29a34f9a27f4863ea70312d00a9df80/src/main/scala/com/amazon/deequ/suggestions/rules)) and pass it to the `ConstraintSuggestionRunner` when executing.